# How to create an xml attribute with special characters using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing

I'm using python to create xml files, and I need to create the attribute *xml:id*

how can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like this <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <doc xml:id="value">Some text</doc>
</root>

Comment: yes exactly, sorry I should've specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the xml.dom.minidom module

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.Document()

ele = doc.createElement("element")
doc.appendChild(ele)
ele.attributes['xml:id']= "something"

print (ele.toxml())
```

Comment: well, I'm using lxml, and I specifically chose it because I need to create something like:  <doc/>tail  . Is this possible using dom??

Comment: do you mean a closing tag </doc> ?

Comment: no, I actually have tags like this <doc/> , just like <br/> in html

Comment: like this <element xml:id="something"/>

Comment: I have updated the answer, so try if it works for you.

Comment: I fail to add a text right after it, I mean like: 
<element xml:id="something"/> some text

Comment: That is another problem and this is a Q&A site and not a site where someone does your whole project step by step. Good luck.